# AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK not working

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

So I am new and have been playing around with `onAccessibilityEvent` and reading `TextViews` that are on the screen from other apps and it is working great, but now I want to be able to use `AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK` to click on some of these. My problem is most of these `TextView`s from other apps do not have the clickable turned on, but they have a pop up that are in a `android.widget.LinearLayout` or `android.widget.FrameLayout` that is clickable. But my code doesn't seem to be clicking them. Any suggestions?

```
public class AutoService extends AccessibilityService 
{
          @TargetApi(16)
          @Override
          public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event)
          {
                 AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();
                 myAdapter.processEvent(source);
          }
}

public class myAdapter
{
    public static void processEvent(final AccessibilityNodeInfo source)
    {
         final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         processSubEvent(source, 0, sb);
         final String string = sb.toString();

         if (string == null)
         {
            return;
         }

         clickScreen(source, string.toLowerCase());
    }

private static void processSubEvent(final AccessibilityNodeInfo source, final int n, final StringBuilder sb) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        sb.append("\t");
    }

    if (source != null)
    {
        sb.append(source.getText());
        sb.append("\n");
        final int childCount = source.getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        {
            AccessibilityNodeInfo child = source.getChild(i);
            processSubEvent(child, n + 1, sb);

            if (child != null)
            {
                child.recycle();
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void clickScreen(final AccessibilityNodeInfo source, final String text)
{
     List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> list = source.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText(text);

    for (final AccessibilityNodeInfo node : list)
    {
        node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you agree with me that the problem is in:

```
List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> list = source.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByText(text);
```

> as this method returns a "List", may come to mind at first glance that
>   it returns all the nodes which mentioned in this string. In fact, it
>   scans the string and returns all the nodes that contains, not a part,
>   but the whole string.

In your program, the string given to "clickScreen" contains all the texts of views together. So, you can whether:

- click the view whenever you meet with one of them by:

  ```
  if(child.isClickable()){
      child.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
  }
  ```

  and if you want to click a specific view, you must know its text or part of it in advance (pay attention to "OK" and "Cancel" because it dismiss the screen):

  ```
  child.getText().toString().toLowerCase().contains()("your text");
  ```
- Or put all of them in ArrayList and click what you want later:

  1. to fill the the ArrayList:

     ```
     //create new ArrayList
     public  ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo> clickableViews = new ArrayList<>();

     private static void processSubEvent(final AccessibilityNodeInfo source, final int n, final StringBuilder sb) {
         ...
     if (child != null)
     {
         //fill the ArrayList with clickable views(make sure to put the origin reference because you will recycle child later)
         if(child.isClickable()) {
             clickableViews.add(source.getChild(i));
         }
         ...
     }
     ```
  2. iterate the list and click:

     ```
      for (AccessibilityNodeInfo view : clickableViews) {
         //We only want to click one view per function call! Clicking multiple 
         //views in rapid succession is error prone and functionally ambiguous 
         //meaning it might work in some use cases, and throw exceptions in others.
         if(view.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK)) break;
      }
     ```

Comment: I am new to Arraylist, how would I store the clickable node in that list and then recall it later?

Comment: @Jayce I changed the answer, take a look and:

    `if (answer.isHelpfull()) {
        answer.accept(true);
    } else {
          answer.addComment("your enquiry");
    }`

Comment: Iterating a list of clickables and clicking them is a rough idea. You should probably only click one per call of this function. Clicking a bunch of buttons in rapid succession (milliseconds apart) is a bad idea. It would be a pretty common app that invalidated the screen content after the first such element was clicked, making clicking other nodes meaningless... at best.  Otherwise, this answer is perfect. Will upvote if this problem is addressed.

Comment: it is a good remark, although i meant by: "pay attention to "OK" and "Cancel" because it dismiss the screen" this issue somehow. and from another side, i don't really understand what the questioner meant by this because he insists a lot on it. may be he will put some IFs to make it clear.

Comment: @ChrisCM well what I did was added some filters if (child != null) section, so that it will only get the one node I am looking for. So when it goes to iterate through the list there is actually only one node in there.

Comment: @Jayce: That is awesome, and very valuable. Given this, I'm going to make a minor edit to the code under bullet two. Let me know if it makes sense to you!